# createMaterialTopTabNavigator accepts active background color

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

This may not be the best place to ask this question, but I can't find a true answer anywhere else and it would surprise me if it wasn't a possibility.

I have a bottom tab navigator with four tabs across the bottom. Originally I was using `createBottomTabNavigator` for the bottom tab navigation. It was styled perfectly how I wanted. Like the picture below:
[image]

The problem is (as referenced in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4146 and this GitHub issue: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4236) `createBottomTabNavigator` no longer supports screen animations. So I did as the first issue suggested and implemented `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`. It styled *almost* perfectly. Here is what the style created:
[image]

As you can kind of see, my other styles which made the active text and active white worked, but for the active tab background color, nothing is taking effect.

Here is my relevant code:

```
const tabConfigs = {
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  tabBarOptions: {
    inactiveTintColor: '#425563',
    activeTintColor: '#fff',
    activeBackgroundColor: '#ff6900',
    indicatorStyle: {
      display: 'none',
    },
    showIcon: true,
    tabStyle: {
      width: '100%',
    },
    labelStyle: {
      fontSize: 11,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      marginBottom: 5,
    },
    style: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95)',
      height: 55,
      width: '100%',
      borderTopWidth: 0,
      position: 'absolute',
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      shadowColor: "#000",
      shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 1,
      },
      shadowOpacity: 0.22,
      shadowRadius: 2.22,
    },
  }
};

export default createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  DashboardStack,
  StatusStack,
  ReferralStack,
  MoreStack,
},
tabConfigs
);
```

**How can I make the background of an active tab in `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` orange, just like in `createBottomTabNavigator`?**

Comment: why are you using top navigator now. if you were using bottom tab already you can use it as this one: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-bottom-tab-navigator.html according to the latest docs

Comment: @AnkushRishi honestly because it is what was suggested to use in that first Github issue I linked to. But looking at the docs for that, it doesnt look like I'll have the styling control I'll need anyways.

Comment: I got you and found your error as well! change `activeTintColor` to the color you want to add. currently its white, that's why it is disappearing

Comment: @AnkushRishi that only changes the label color, not the background color

Comment: In that doc link from above, there is a property called `barStyle` that you can use to style the background.

Answer (score 15):

`createMaterialTopTabNavigator` does not directly have a way to change the active background color, however you could use the indicator.

```
indicatorStyle: {
  height: '100%',
  backgroundColor: '#ff6900'
}
```

With this method you could even add a borderRadius to it to have a circular selection!

Comment: Thank you u save my day :"))

Comment: use the focus function